# If an exercise says "the measure of the smallest angle in a triangle is $20$", does that mean no other angle can have measure $20$?

Tags: geometry

I have a question about this exercise:

> If the measure of the smallest angle in a triangle is 20, then the measure of the greatest possible angle in this triangle is .....
>   $$a ) 90$$
>   $$b )140$$
>   $$c ) 159$$
>   $$d ) 160$$

My question :

> Does the word "smallest" mean that no other angle in the triangle is of measure 20, or is it okay to have another angle that size? Because, if there is no other one of measure 20, the answer is 90; but, if it's okay, the answer is 140.

Comment: I would tend to say that a triangle can have 2 or even 3 smallest angles.

Comment: It's reasonable to consider "smallest angle" ambiguous. Almost-certainly, the author intends that "there is no angle with measure smaller than this one", which allows that there could be angles with measure *equal* to that one. An author that intended there to be only one $20^\circ$ angle would probably be more explicit, writing something like "the *unique* smallest angle".

Comment: How are you concluding that "if there is no other one of measure 20, the answer is 90"? If there is no other angle of measure 20, there *could* be one of measure, say, 23 ... or 45 ... or 67; in these cases, the largest angle would be 137, or 115, or 93. None of those are 90.

Comment: I agree with you that the text is not obvious well and its up to who put the question . @Blue

Comment: I mean the suitable measure from the choices not in general @Blue

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking is a valid question: there is a difference between the minimal element and the least element.

In this question, I would assume that it's OK for the other angle to be 20. Because if not, then there is no measurement for the 2nd smallest angle. What would it be? 20.01? 20.0001? It's analogous to asking if there is a smallest positive real number.

Comment: What do you mean by (there is no measurement for the other angle ) ? If there is no other angle of measure 20 then the answer is 90 and the 3rd angle is of measure70@nilpo

Comment: @HussienMohamed Certainly not. The smallest angle 20 and the largest one 90 would mean the third angle _must_ be 70. But the requirements enforce only the smallest angle to be 20, and a triangle with angles 20-25-135 fits this requirement – but there is no fitting answer!

Comment: The measure 135 is not mentioned in the choices @CiaPan

Comment: @HussienMohamed That's right! It's not there. But this answer is correct, hence it must be present in the choices, along with continuum of other valid answers – **IF** we assume 'the smallest angle' means 'smaller than both remaining angles'. The impossibility shows the assumption is false; as a result 'the smallest' means smaller than or equal to each remaining angle'.